# Any way to keep Ubuntu settings when resizing partitions?

Tags: partitioning, 12.10, settings, windows-vista

A few days ago I set up Ubuntu on my old Laptop. I used a Live CD with version 12.10 on it. I am new to Linux, but everything went fine. However, it would not let me split off a big partition from my hard drive(with Windows Vista installed) to use for Ubuntu.

This was fine in the beginning, but because I only had a very small partition for Ubuntu, it has now started to complain about low memory/unable to save bookmarks, etc.

Now I would like to resize the Ubuntu partition so that it becomes bigger. Problem here is that windows programs don't seem to see the Ubuntu partition, and programs ran on Ubuntu like Gparted are somehow unable to read the windows Partition Manager table (Or whatever it is called.) Basically they see the whole disk as one big blob, instead of partitions.

Strange thing is, that in the file system on Linux, I can see and use the windows partitions without a problem.

The only option that is left that I can see, is to re-install Ubuntu completely, getting space from that new partition. My biggest problem with that is however, that I would lose all programs and settings I've installed so far.

So my question: Is there a way to back up my settings and programs so I can load them on the newly installed Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

your settings are basically stored within your /home/YourUsername folder (home folder, or just ~/ ) so if you back it up, it will restore all your SETTINGS, not your applications. but you can easily reinstall them trough the software center.

i suggest you split your whole hardrive into 3 partitions: 20gb[ntfs] for windows 20gb[ext4] for ubuntu and the rest becomes your DATA[ext2] partition. on ubuntu you simply define your DATA partition as /home, your ubuntu partition as /, and the windows as /windows. on windows you'll have to install a ext driver, and just constantly mount it as D: this setting works great if you use windows just once in a while, but is a pain if you primarily use it.